# linearlayout view in disorder

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with an ImageView and a TextView inside. But the TextView is placed before my ImageView and I have no idea why...

my XML file :

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_titre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layoutDirection="inherit">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/roue_dentee"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/engrenage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titre_diagramme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: The result]

I change the text inside my TextView programmatically, but I think it's not linked.

**UPDATE**

This XML works perfectly. Somewhere in my code there was a `bringToFront()` on the imageView...

Sorry for wasting your time and thank you everybody for your help !

Comment: remove  android:layout_weight="1"from textview

Comment: if I do this, my imageView is compressed because my textview is in matchparent

Comment: then use Relative layout with imageview as alignparent_left

Comment: why layoutDirection is given?

Comment: than         android:layout_weight="1" of your imageview

Comment: give weightsum=2 to linearlayout and layout weight as 1 to both imageview and textview

Comment: I tried all your advices and nothing work.. It is really weird.. So I change my LinearLayout in RelativeLayout... Thank you @Divyesh

Comment: is it worked with relative layout??

Comment: @Divyesh, yes it works perfectly !

Comment: can you post the screen shot of the issue screen

Comment: @EKN updated with the screen

Comment: From your code there is no chance for the disorder issue. Why you use android:layoutDirection="inherit" in your linear layout.  Please remove it and try.

Comment: @EKN we are ok on the fact that there is no chance for the disorder issue... I make some changes programmatically like the text or the background but nothing justifying the disorder.
For the android:layoutDirection="inherit" it was just a test but it changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  `android:layout_weight="1"` from your text view

If you want to add both the elements to equal size on screen make sure each view(both Image view and Text View) adds layout_weight

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: change the width of your text view to 0 dp,then it will work                        
 its better if you give the weight property as i mentioned in my answer as it will allow the linear layout to know how much space to give

Answer (score 0):

Just change the layout_width of your TextView to 0dp

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/container_titre"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layoutDirection="inherit">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/roue_dentee"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/engrenage" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titre_diagramme"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then your TextView will be appear next to your ImageView with width = width of parent view - width of image view

Comment: Did you use same code when you ask? Because if you change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, it will not work.

Comment: I just posted my new XML, you can check it

Answer (score 0):

I replace my linearLayout by a relativeLayout and it works perfectly

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_titre"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/roue_dentee"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/engrenage"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titre_diagramme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/roue_dentee"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/roue_dentee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the result :
[image]